# How to pass message to child process through named pipes in Windows

Tags: c++, windows

I know how to do this through an anonymous pipe, just create an anonymous pipe and before executing createprocess(), set the startupInfo as follow:

```
startupInfo.hStdInput = hstdinRead;//hstdinRead is the handle of the pipe
startupInfo.hStdOutput = hstdoutWrite;
```

But can I do the same when I use a named pipe?
I have tried to create a named pipe through CreateNamedPipeA function and do similar above, but things don't seem to work at all.
Should I do some pre-settings or is it just impossible to communicate between a process and it's child process through a named pipe?

And : My child process is an unchangable .exe, so I must do all these things before createprocess() function in the parent process.

20180804: thanks for your comments, I am still polishing my English, and my codes using named pipes are like these.
First I create two named pipes and I have confirmed they succeed:

```
inFileWrite = CreateNamedPipeA("\\\\.\\pipe\\cmder_in", PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, PIPE_TYPE_BYTE, 10, 4096, 4096, 0, &saAttr);//for writting to the child process
outFileRead = CreateNamedPipeA("\\\\.\\pipe\\cmder_out", PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, PIPE_TYPE_BYTE, 10, 4096, 4096, 0, &saAttr);//for reading from the child process
```

Then I try to connect to these pipes in the same process(I am a bit confused about this step)

```
inFileRead = CreateFileA("\\\\.\\pipe\\cmder_in", GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, &saAttr)
outFileWrite = CreateFileA("\\\\.\\pipe\\cmder_out", GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, &saAttr);
```

After some other init steps, I create a STARTUPINFO struct for childprocess, in which I try to redirect its std input/output:

```
startupInfo.hStdInput = inFileRead;
startupInfo.hStdOutput = outFileWrite;
```

Finally it's the createprocess:

```
char cmdLine[] = { "cmd" };
CreateProcess(NULL,
    cmdLine,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    TRUE,
    0,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    &startupInfo,
    &procInfo);
```

These all codes seem to work well, but when I write an command like "cd .." and try to read the result from childprocess through the pipe, it reads nothing. I think the problem is I didn't redirect childprocess's stdin/out successfully.

I succeeded in doing similar things by using an anonymous pipe or named pipes in Linux. I am new to windows programming, and this problem has stuck me for a long time.

Comment: What does things doesn't seem to work mean? Please share more code and explain in more details.

Comment: A handle to a named pipe is also a file handle, and you write to or read from a named pipe just like you do with files.

Comment: exist only one pipe type. anonymous pipe and named pipe is the same

Comment: True, though an anonymous pipe is only one-way, whereas a named pipe can be one-way or bi-directional.  So, you don't actually need 2 named pipes, but if you do use 2 then don't use `PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX` for them since they will be used one-way each.

Comment: [here's an example of setting up two pipes to a process. one for stdin and the other for stdout and sterr.](http://www.ivorykite.com/winpipe.html)

Comment: @RemyLebeau That works for me, thank you! Though I am a bit confused about the reason I failed before, maybe the problem is beacuse I used PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX.

Comment: @Adam I am stuck with the same problem now, can you share your code that finally worked?